# Elegant way to check a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR to be all zero

Tags: vhdl

I'm working with Xilinx and VHDL2008.
Is there an builtin elegant way to detect if a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is all zero?
I use

> if my_vector = (my_vector'range => '0') then

at the moment and hope that there is a more elegant way. Maybe something like this:

> if is_zero(my_vector) then

I could try to write a function to do this, but maybe there is something built in that I didn't find yet.

What is the best option you know? It should work on constraint and unconstrained vectors.

Comment: hm, what about an equality comparison to 0?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008707/comparing-a-long-std-logic-vector-to-zeros

Comment: Writing an is_zero function (or a library of common functions in a package) is dead easy and can clean up your code nicely

Comment: VHDL -2008 has unary logical operators. `if not (or my_vector) then` here relying on an implicit condition operator. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9. Expressions 9.1 General NOTE 2 (telling us the parentheses are required without resort to parsing the condition expression) and 9.2.9 Condition operator.  The unary "or" operator is used to detect all '0's, the "not" to provide a '1' converted to a Boolean by the implicit condition operator.

Comment: `function iszero (vec: std_logic_vector) return Boolean is 
begin
return or vec = '0';
end function;`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the unary operators, e.g.:

- and
- nand
- or
- nor

```vhdl
signal my_vector: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
if and my_vector then
    -- Do something for all 1...
elsif nand my_vector then
    -- Do something for at least one 0...
elsif or my_vector then
    -- Do something for at least one 1...
elsif nor my_vector then
    -- Do something for all 0...
end if;
```

Or you could use the functions defined in [std_logic_1164](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/ieee2008/std_logic_1164.vhdl), e.g.:

```vhdl
function "and"  (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "nand" (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "or"   (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "nor"  (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
```

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
...
signal my_vector: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
...
if and(my_vector) then
    -- Do something for all 1...
elsif nand(my_vector) then
    -- Do something for at least one 0...
elsif or(my_vector) then
    -- Do something for at least one 1...
elsif nor(my_vector) then
    -- Do something for all 0...
end if;
```

Comment: Worth to mention that this requires VHDL-2008…

Answer (score 0):

you can use a short function whose name depends on you, like this one:

```
function    check_for_one( value: std_logic_vector ) return std_logic is
variable compare: std_logic_vector( (value'length-1) downto 0) :=  (others => '0');
variable holder: std_logic_vector( (value'length-1) downto 0);
variable res: std_logic;
begin
    
    holder := not( not(value) and not(compare));
    if(holder = compare) then
        res := '0';
    else
        res := '1';
    end if;
    return res; end function;
```

in my case I was checking the condition that there is a '1' in the vector